# linking search results to a its own detail page

Tags: python, django, api, frameworks

This is a django related question:

I am doing an assignment where we are playing around making a search bar then afterwards letting each individual search result linked to its own page with more details. In this context we are doing a job search engine and I need assistance in when you click each jobs posting, it takes you to a separate page with more info about the job. We already made templates for all the pages. I understand that we have to make a request to the api again after doing it for the view function in the search bar and also use templating got fill up out the detailed search results.Im just not sure how would I apply these concepts to the html file that w ehave.

here's the code
**View function code**

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):

    context = {
        'example_context_variable': 'Change me.',
    }

    return render(request, 'pages/home.html', context)


def search_results(request):
    search_query = request.GET['searchterm']

    context = {
        'result_count': 0,
        'search_term': search_query,
     }

    context['results_count'] = 0

    url = 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?location=bay+area&description='
    url += search_query

    response = requests.get(url)
    results_data = response.json()
    job_list =[]
    for result in results_data:
        job_list.append(result)


    context['job_results'] = job_list


    return render(request, 'pages/search_results.html', context)
```

**Search Results Page**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Search Results
{% endblock title %}

{% block additional_styles %}
<style>
    body {
        background-color: white;
    }
</style>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<div id="home-content" class="container">
  <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-3"></div> <!-- Column for spacing -->

      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="mt-5 mb-3 text-center">
            <h1>Search Results</h1>
          </div>

<form method="GET" action="/search-results/">
  <div class="input-group mb-2">
    <input name="searchterm" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Let's find a job..." />
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Search</button></a>
  </div>
</div>

</form>

<!-- 2start -->
<p>You Searched for: {{search_term}}</p>
{% for job in job_results %}
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="/detailed-search-results/" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-1">{{job.title}}</h5>
    </div>
    <div>
      <small class="text-muted">{{job.location}}</small>
    </div>
  </a> 
</div>
<br>
{% endfor %}
<!-- End -->

{% endblock content %}
```

**detailed Search Results Html file **

So far when you click on a posting it takes you to the detailed search result page without anything on it.

Comment: And? What exactly is the problem? Please post the template code rendering search results and what is it that you are trying to do and what is not happening

Comment: @MohitC I updated the question with more code rendering search results. So far each posting takes you to a blank detailed page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have hyperlinked each job posting to `/detailed-search-results/`.
Looking at the API response, you need to change it to `job.url`

Replace your for loop with this:

```
{% for job in job_results %}
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="{{ job.url }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-1">{{job.title}}</h5>
    </div>
    <div>
      <small class="text-muted">{{job.location}}</small>
    </div>
  </a> 
</div>
<br>
{% endfor %}
```